# Selenium testing on dynamic pages in IE

Tags: internet-explorer, selenium

The Selenium html-script tests one page containing several related drop-down menus. Related like selecting some option from one menu updates contain of the next menu correspondingly. For example, select State from one menu and next menu will contain names of that selected state cities.
Script works fine when executed in Firefox, but it fails when executed in IE. After script selects option from first drop-down menu, the content of the next menu remains unchanged. Therefore, script unable to find required option and it fails.
Is there a way to force that menu update from the script?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If functionality works manually then try with `fireEven blur` or `submit` selected field.